# Dúvida básica: A função simples não retorna nenhum valor - javascript

Tags: javascript

Alguém pode me ajudar e me explicar qual foi o meu erro? Obrigado.

```html
function tipoDados(dado){
    switch(dado){
        case dado == Number :
            console.log(`O dado recebido é um ${dado}.`);
            break;
        case dado == String :
            console.log(`O dado recebido é um ${dado}.`);
            break;
        case dado == Boolean :
                console.log(`O dado recebido é um ${dado}.`);
                break;
    }
}

tipoDados(56)
tipoDados(true)
tipoDados('string')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você deve utilizar o [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) para verificar o tipo do dado.

```js
function tipoDados(dado){
   console.log(typeof dado)
}

tipoDados(56)
tipoDados("Olá mundo")
tipoDados(true)
```

Comment: Perfeito, é isso mesmo, não prestei atenção. Muitíssimo obrigado, você me ajudou bastante!

Comment: Se puder aceitar minha resposta eu agradeço